# variable has space separated values I need to get groups of 3 values for next script

Tags: bash, ksh

I have a shell script environmental variable being populated by an sql command
the sql command is returning multiple records of 3 columns.  each record I need to pass to another shell script.

```
QUERYRESULT=`${SQLPLUS_COMMAND} -s ${SQL_USER}/${SQL_PASSWD}@${SQL_SCHEMA}<<endl
set heading off  feedback off
select col1, col2,  col3
from mytable
where ......)
order by ......
;
exit
endl`
echo ${QUERYRESULT}
```

outputs a single line of all columns space separated, all variables are guaranteed to be not null

```
 val1 val2 val3 val1 val2 val3 val1 val2 val3 ......
```

I need to call the following for each record

```
nextScript.bash val1 val2 val3
```

I can also run the query but count the records to determine how many times I need to call nextScript.bash.

any thoughts on how to get from a single env variable of multiple 3 parameters to my executing the next script?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand ... you could just run three queries, one for each column (assuming each column stores 3 values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the use of a variable:

```
( ${SQLPLUS_COMMAND} -s ${SQL_USER}/${SQL_PASSWD}@${SQL_SCHEMA}<<endl
set heading off  feedback off
select col1, col2,  col3
from mytable
where ......)
order by ......
;
exit
endl
) | while read line;do echo $line; done
```

Comment: ok thanks that is a great help.  Now once the read is done processing my sql output it is waiting for further input from the command line.  How do I get it to end the while loop once it is done reading the sqlplus output

Comment: @petercooke sorry, I didn't fully test my solution, I updated it, it should work now.

Comment: Hi an interesting aspect col3 is a time stamp.  read is reading col1 and col2 as part of one line and the col3 as part of another line.  any thoughts on why that would occur